# Convert "Never fully converted" provinces

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

I'm playing Turkey and I'm trying to convert all my provinces into Sunni. However, I have some Dhimmi/zealots provinces that say that they "never will be Sunni".

[image]

My question is: is it possible to convert them at all? I don't care if I should just kill every zealot in my province, provoke them on revolt and them kill all or whatever. But I don't see any possibility including cruel ones that could accomplish that.

P.S. Of course, I don't mention cheating like installing mods or something, it's about hardcore play - no saves, no mods, vanilla game with DLC.

---

Thanks to @Nicolas , I found the right button, here is a screenshot to complete an answer:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For provinces controlled by the Dhimmi, simply remove the Dhimmi estate from the province. This will anger the Dhimmi and create revolt-risk in the province, but that'll go down eventually.

Zeal is even easier: just wait. Religious Zeal is a province modifier that occurs when a province has recently been converted, and goes away after 30 years.

Edit: Screenshot grabbed from Google. I haven't played in a while, but when I last played the building interface looked like this.

[image: Province mode]

If you click on the icon square (next to where it says nobility, in this case), you can change which estate controls the province. It can be accessed by clicking the build tab hanging off of the right side of the province interface, seen below:

[image: Main province ui]

Comment: Sorry, but how could I remove estate? I do believe it's just a territory. Can you be more detailed, please. Screenshots would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, it was hard, but I just clicked every button on the screen after I finally found it.  Thank you. P.S. Am I right that after missionary fraction would dissapear completely?

Comment: I am unsure of what you mean by fraction in this context, sorry.

Comment: I mean "Estate'. Sorry, I came from Stellaris where it's called so :)

Comment: Ah, I see. As a Stellaris player myself, I should have guessed. I've never actually destroyed any estates in EU, but the results of a Google search seem to imply that this may be the case.